# How to connect deployed Heroku app to Django server

Tags: django, reactjs, heroku, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

I have deployed heroku app that is based on `Django`, and `React` but whenever i want to **login** into the deployed app i'm getting an error

> POST http://localhost:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Initially i had my react login api as `http://localhost:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/` then changed it to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/` but i keep getting the same error.

**login** file in react

```
// LOGIN
export const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  const body = JSON.stringify({ email, password });

  await axios
    .post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/jwt/create/", body)
    .then((res) => {
      try {        
        dispatch({
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
        });
        dispatch(createMessage({ login: "Login Successful" }));
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(res, error);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_FAIL,
      });
    });
}
```

Comment: have you checked login from postman of your heroku app?

Comment: Yes, it;s working.